# RAM usage extremely high even without anything running?

Tags: memory

Today, I woke my PC up from suspend and it was very slow. I suspected a high RAM usage, then `free` gave me:

```
renan@vector:~> free -tm
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7785        5957         264         209        1563        1359
Swap:          8395          27        8368
Total:        16181        5984        8633
```

Then I closed everything I was running (Firefox with a bunch of tabs, basically) and the RAM usage was still high:

```
renan@vector:~> free -tm
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7785        5109        1180         129        1494        2287
Swap:          8395          27        8368
Total:        16181        5136        9549
```

And even after logging off and shutting my display manager down the RAM usage
is still high:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7785        4488        1821          47        1475        2989
Swap:          8395           6        8389
Total:        16181        4494       10210
```

I tried the "ps_mem" utility and all the processes are only using ~300 MB RAM, so why is 'free' saying I'm using nearly 4.5 GB? Something doesn't add up.

```
 Private  +   Shared  =  RAM used   Program

160.0 KiB +  33.5 KiB = 193.5 KiB   agetty
188.0 KiB +  34.5 KiB = 222.5 KiB   vnstatd
324.0 KiB +  42.5 KiB = 366.5 KiB   auditd
308.0 KiB +  75.5 KiB = 383.5 KiB   rtkit-daemon
352.0 KiB +  56.5 KiB = 408.5 KiB   irqbalance
492.0 KiB +  53.5 KiB = 545.5 KiB   lvmetad
504.0 KiB + 161.5 KiB = 665.5 KiB   mcelog
616.0 KiB + 168.5 KiB = 784.5 KiB   agent
648.0 KiB + 160.5 KiB = 808.5 KiB   xfconfd
736.0 KiB + 113.5 KiB = 849.5 KiB   avahi-daemon
712.0 KiB + 177.5 KiB = 889.5 KiB   gconfd-2
652.0 KiB + 249.5 KiB = 901.5 KiB   master
884.0 KiB +  55.5 KiB = 939.5 KiB   cron
812.0 KiB + 164.5 KiB = 976.5 KiB   gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
812.0 KiB + 170.5 KiB = 982.5 KiB   gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
780.0 KiB + 221.5 KiB =   1.0 MiB   sshd
684.0 KiB + 319.5 KiB =   1.0 MiB   login
  1.0 MiB +  66.5 KiB =   1.0 MiB   nscd
808.0 KiB + 301.5 KiB =   1.1 MiB   at-spi-bus-launcher
856.0 KiB + 254.5 KiB =   1.1 MiB   at-spi2-registryd
944.0 KiB + 170.5 KiB =   1.1 MiB   gvfsd-metadata
  1.0 MiB + 123.5 KiB =   1.1 MiB   dconf-service
  1.0 MiB +  80.5 KiB =   1.1 MiB   mount.ntfs
176.0 KiB + 964.5 KiB =   1.1 MiB   smbd-notifyd
184.0 KiB +   1.0 MiB =   1.2 MiB   cleanupd
  1.0 MiB + 242.5 KiB =   1.3 MiB   obexd
952.0 KiB + 386.5 KiB =   1.3 MiB   systemd-logind
944.0 KiB + 480.5 KiB =   1.4 MiB   qmgr
  1.2 MiB + 181.5 KiB =   1.4 MiB   gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
  1.1 MiB + 290.5 KiB =   1.4 MiB   gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
  1.4 MiB + 144.5 KiB =   1.6 MiB   smartd
  1.5 MiB + 114.5 KiB =   1.6 MiB   bluetoothd
  1.3 MiB + 424.5 KiB =   1.7 MiB   gvfsd-trash
524.0 KiB +   1.2 MiB =   1.7 MiB   lpqd
  1.3 MiB + 554.5 KiB =   1.8 MiB   pickup
  1.8 MiB + 191.5 KiB =   1.9 MiB   ModemManager
  2.0 MiB +  23.5 KiB =   2.1 MiB   haveged
  1.8 MiB + 319.5 KiB =   2.2 MiB   upowerd
  2.1 MiB + 280.5 KiB =   2.4 MiB   wpa_supplicant
  1.9 MiB + 526.5 KiB =   2.5 MiB   cupsd
  1.9 MiB + 727.5 KiB =   2.6 MiB   sudo
  2.4 MiB +   1.2 MiB =   3.5 MiB   dhclient (2)
  3.2 MiB + 424.5 KiB =   3.6 MiB   udisksd
  3.4 MiB + 343.5 KiB =   3.8 MiB   systemd-udevd
  1.4 MiB +   2.4 MiB =   3.8 MiB   smbd
  2.4 MiB +   1.4 MiB =   3.8 MiB   goa-identity-service
  2.6 MiB +   1.3 MiB =   3.9 MiB   nmbd
  3.8 MiB +  77.5 KiB =   3.9 MiB   rsyslogd
  3.7 MiB + 238.5 KiB =   3.9 MiB   accounts-daemon
  3.6 MiB + 823.0 KiB =   4.4 MiB   (sd-pam) (2)
  3.3 MiB +   1.1 MiB =   4.5 MiB   lightdm (3)
  4.0 MiB + 538.5 KiB =   4.5 MiB   gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
  4.1 MiB + 651.0 KiB =   4.7 MiB   gvfsd (2)
  4.2 MiB + 766.0 KiB =   4.9 MiB   dbus-daemon (4)
  6.0 MiB +  43.5 KiB =   6.0 MiB   bash
  6.2 MiB + 498.5 KiB =   6.7 MiB   NetworkManager
  4.8 MiB +   2.5 MiB =   7.2 MiB   systemd (3)
  7.8 MiB + 339.5 KiB =   8.2 MiB   systemd-journald
  7.8 MiB + 473.0 KiB =   8.3 MiB   gvfsd-fuse (2)
  5.8 MiB +   3.8 MiB =   9.6 MiB   goa-daemon
  8.2 MiB +   3.8 MiB =  12.0 MiB   deja-dup-monitor
 20.8 MiB + 398.5 KiB =  21.2 MiB   polkitd
 20.9 MiB +   2.0 MiB =  22.9 MiB   applet.py
 31.7 MiB +   8.4 MiB =  40.1 MiB   Xorg
 44.5 MiB +   9.0 MiB =  53.5 MiB   lightdm-gtk-greeter
---------------------------------
                        298.3 MiB
=================================
```

I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed with kernel 4.18.15 and my desktop is MATE. Why is `free` reporting so high a RAM usage even with nearly nothing running?

Comment: Another compelling case of https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: But why would most of my RAM be taken even without anything running?

Comment: Caching, please read the article.